# Xubuntu audio not working (15.04)

Tags: sound, xubuntu, 15.04

I'm new to ubuntu and I've just fresh installed Xubuntu 15.04 on a Netbook.
I've got a problem with speakers since they don't work.
I've checked a lot of threads but no one of them lead me to a solution.
No sound option is displayed in settings>hardware.

But i guess the card is detected 'cause:

```
aplay -l
```

returns:

```
    **** Lista di PLAYBACK dispositivi hardware ****
    scheda 0: Intel [HDA Intel], dispositivo 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
    Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
    Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
```

Edit: required screenshots.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3SHN.jpg)

Comment: i ran the same command and i've got 3 devices, Analog, digital and HDMI. Run `pavucontrol`, and check the "Port" options on the "Output Devices" tab to see if you can change it to something like **Speakers** or **Headphones**.

Comment: I did what you said and it was already set on speakers, actually when I use some audio-related app (youtube for example) the "blue bar" indicating sound moves, so he Os recives sound from the app. The problem is that sound doesn't come out of the speakers. I'll update a screen in the main thread.